# Резиновая вёрстка с помощью font-size: calc(100vw/1440*10)

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Нашел на просторах интернета один из способов резиновой вёрстки.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему `font-size: calc(100vw / 1440 * 10);` применяется к каждому значению, будь то блок или шрифт? (Почему меняется ширина и высота блока которая задана через width и height, почему font-size влияет на изменение высоты и ширины блока) Как это работает?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(100vw / 1440 * 10);
}

div {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Базовая разметка HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Адаптивный блок</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Единица `rem` считает размер относительно размера шрифта. Увеличив сам шрифт вы увеличиваете `rem`, соответственно и размеры которые заданы через `rem`

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь вариант применить этот лайфхак локально к блоку или секции? Или только таким способом задавая через `html { font-size: calc(100vw / 1440 * 10); }` @Арман

Comment: `rem` будет считать размер относительно тега `html`, `em` относительно родительского блока. Можете использовать его и `calc()`  для нужных вам расчетов

Comment: @Арман Спасибо!